# If-Statement hadn't been obeserved

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my Unity project I have a script attached to a couple of prefabs. Every few seconds a random prefab is spawned. This is a part of my attached script:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.transform.CompareTag("ground"))
    {
        if (transform.gameObject.name == "FallingKeule(Clone)") 
        {
            Destroy(transform.gameObject);
        }
        if (transform.gameObject.name == "FallingHeart(Clone)")
        {
            Destroy(transform.gameObject);
        }
        if (transform.gameObject.name == "FallingCup(Clone)")
        {
            Destroy(transform.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            print("You lost a life!");
            Player.GetComponent<Colliding>().LostLife();
            Destroy(transform.gameObject);
        }               
    }
}
```

If a GameObject is spawned by random and it hit's the ground, and it is a "FallingKeule(Clone)" --> "(Clone)" because the prefab is cloned by it's initalisation the Code from

```
if (transform.gameObject.name == "FallingKeule(Clone)")
```

isn't be done! The else code is been done:

```
else
{
    print("You lost a life!");
    Player.GetComponent<Colliding>().LostLife();
    Destroy(transform.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Should the middle two if statements be else if?

Comment: use `else if` after each of your `if`s. But if you are going to use `else if`, then you can use `switch/case` instead.

Comment: Now would be a good time to actually use a debugger and see for yourself why it enters the else case.

Comment: The previous comments are correct, just another tip: don't do comparisons with the clones' names, use Tags: it's the correct way to go, in Unity, and they exist exactly for these situations.

Comment: You  shold use `switch`, that makes it clearer. Otherwise you should at least use `if...else if...else if` instead of `ìf...if...if`

Comment: `if([is the player]) { Log("lost a life!") } else { Destroy(); }`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `else if` statement:

```
if (transform.gameObject.name == "FallingKeule(Clone)") 
{
    Destroy(transform.gameObject);
}
else if (transform.gameObject.name == "FallingHeart(Clone)")
{
    Destroy(transform.gameObject);
}
else if (transform.gameObject.name == "FallingCup(Clone)")
{
    Destroy(transform.gameObject);
}
else
{
    print("You lost a life!");
    Player.GetComponent<Colliding>().Destroy(transform.gameObject);
}
```

or much better:

```
var gameObjectName = transform.gameObject.name;
if(gameObjectName == "FallingKeule(Clone)" || gameObjectName == "FallingHeart(Clone)" || gameObjectName == "FallingCup(Clone)")
{
    Destroy(transform.gameObject);
}
else
{
    print("You lost a life!");
    Player.GetComponent<Colliding>().Destroy(transform.gameObject);
}
```

or even:

```
string[] dObjects = new string[] { "FallingKeule(Clone)", "FallingHeart(Clone)", "FallingCup(Clone)" };

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.transform.CompareTag("ground"))
    {
        if(dObjects.Contains(transform.gameObject.name))
        {
            Destroy(transform.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            print("You lost a life!");
            Player.GetComponent<Colliding>().Destroy(transform.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or even better, use tags instead of names.

Comment: Ok, you were faster, I was still typing. I'd add that OP's `If...If...If...else...` makes the `else` always execute if the third `if` is `false`, regardless of the previous `if`s.

Comment: @TJWolschon Correct.

Comment: @TJWolschon I read this before, but I need the falling objects tag to be "fallingObject"

Comment: @Jul Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @DavidG I think `string[]` with `Contains`will be more readable.

Comment: I wrote that before your string array. However, that has a downside in that the array is created every time. If you're going to do that, make it static.

Comment: @DavidG Yeap, I know when you wrote that, I'm not saying anything, and **Jul** please take  note what **DavidG** said.

Comment: @DavidG one question, he can also create that array as a class field (not static) then use it inside method, right? (I'm not familiar how unity's classes would be created/gc-ed during run-time)

Comment: Well as long as that class doesn't get disposed and re-created, then yes. Unity behaves the same as 'classic' in that regard.